# Get All Property's From A User in Flash CS2

Tags: getproperty

I have this:

```
public function saveProfile() {
this.setProperty("picture",factory.getClass("userProfile").getProperty("picture"),"no");
this.setProperty("gender",factory.getClass("userProfile").getProperty("gender"),"no");
this.setProperty("state",factory.getClass("userProfile").getProperty("state"),"no");
this.setProperty("city",factory.getClass("userProfile").getProperty("city"),"no");
this.setProperty("marital",factory.getClass("userProfile").getProperty("marital"),"no");
this.setProperty("about",factory.getClass("userProfile").getProperty("about"),"no");
}
```

factory.getClass("userProfile") functions:

```
public function setProperty(property:String, value:String) {
        _profile[property] = value;
      }

public function getProperty(property:String) {
    if (_profile[property] == undefined) {
        return "";
    }
    return _profile[property];
}
```

what i wanna do is:

this getProperty - setProperty returns the values from a specific user.
I want to get the properties from another user ex:

```
    public function saveProfile(username:String) {

  this.setProperty("picture",factory.getClass("userProfile").getProperty("picture"),"no"); ->
from the user username:String i ask to   
    etc...
    }
```

If anyone can help me to change the getProperty, setProperty functions in the userprofile class to give me the property's from the username i ask.

Thanks a lot!
Regards